# Apache as a proxy for multiple nginx servers

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, bitnami

I'm starting from the bitnami jenkins stack. Everything is working perfectly with jenkins.

http://sample:8080/jenkins (works fine)

I'm trying to add additional directories to apache to proxy to nginx:

http://sample:8080/other_tool

I can get to the other_tool homepage, but references to that other tool break down because they are looking for http://sample:8080/relative_url rather than http://sample:8080/other_tool/relative_url

I can pull config settings from the necessary files as needed, but it is on an air-gapped network so wholesale posting would be a challenge

The apache conf looks like:

```
<Directory /other_tool>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:9999
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9999
</Directory>
```

The nginx configuration is a standard "/" with root directory. I'm not as familiar with nginx so I can't recall the exact information off the top of my head. If needed I will provide it.

I could try to switch the jenkins hosting over to nginx, but I'm not sure that simplifies anything.

I can't open more ports on the machine. I can't use a subdomain as that would require additional DNS entries that I do not control.

Ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. The Jenkins solution works because Apache is using /jenkins to serve the Jenkins app and it's also running using /jenkins in Tomcat. In your case you have multiple solutions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/561892/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-reverse-proxy)

Comment: Am I understanding you that the proxying to ajp:// isn't performing some "magic" behind the scenes to work, but instead the jenkins w/in bitnami was setup to work in /jenkins? If so that alleviates my "Why can't I get this to work if jenkins worked!?!?!"

I'm usually a "systems" guy more than a web guy and this whole process is reminding me why. Apache -> nginx -> uwsgi...how many layers of abstraction is enough?